# c++ ensure object is assigned to a set of objects

Tags: c++

I have a design problem in a modeling & simulation program I'm writing.  All the components of the model are organized into a tree data structure, and for this to work, each component needs to have a pointer to its parent object.  To avoid technical details, I've made it into an analogy:

I have a base class that handles all the tree functionality:

```
class node {};
```

And the following derived classes that represent the simulation components:

```
class turtle : public node {};
class clam : public node {};
class dog : public node {};
```

With further subcomponents:

```
class leg : public node {
  node* _parent;
  /*Some functions relevant to a leg*/
};

class shell : public node {
  node* _parent;
  /*Some functions relevant to a shell*/
};
```

My problem is that I want to ensure that a leg is only ever assigned to a turtle or a dog, and that a shell is only ever assigned to a turtle or a clam.  The dog class doesn't have the functionality to handle a child of type `shell`, and likewise a clam can't handle children of type `leg`.

I was thinking of making `shell` and `leg` class templates, where their parent type would be the template argument.  Then I could make constructor template specializations for only the parent types that I want each class to have.  Is this a good way of solving this problem, or is there some other c++ feature I should be looking at?

Comment: You're falling into the typical "inheritance must fit real-world models" trap. See: circle vs shape problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have interfaces for certainly available functionality and properties, and mix these in as needed. To create interfaces in c++ use pure virtual functions

```
class leg;
class shell;

struct IAnimalWithShell {
    void addShell(shell* shell) = 0;
    ~IAnimalWithShell() = default;
};

struct IAnimalWithLegs {
    void addLegs(const std::vector<leg*>&) = 0;
    ~IAnimalWithLegs() = default;
};
```

---

```
class turtle : public node, public IAnimalWithShell, public IAnimalWithLegs {
    // ...
public:
    void addShell(shell* shell) {
        // Implementation
    }
    void addLegs(const std::vector<leg*>& legs) {
        // Implementation
    }
};

class clam : public node, public IAnimalWithShell {
    // ...
public:
    void addShell(shell* shell) {
        // Implementation
    }
};
```

---

```
class dog : public node, public IAnimalWithLegs {
    // ...
public:
    void addLegs(const std::vector<leg*>& legs) {
        // Implementation
    }
};
```

I hope you get the idea.

As you were asking for design, here are some of the relevant patterns

- [Composite](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite)
- [Visitor](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor)

These discuss the consequences for a design structured like explained above.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that best fits my situation.  I tried to do this using multiple inheritance myself but couldn't figure it out.  Your way makes sense.

Comment: @user3879653 Not really sure, it implies lot of runtime checks for available interfaces. Your primary approach, making use of templates, wasn't a that bad idea. I've added another answer elaborating on this.

Comment: what prevents someone to call addshell with a leg as a parameter ? i think you ment addshell(shell* myshell) and not node*

Answer (score 1):

I would personally move the constraint checking code to dedicated factory classes, for example:

```
class TurtleFactory {
public:
    node * newTurtle() const {
        node * t = new turtle;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            t->addChild(new leg);
        t->addChild(new shell);
        return t;
    }

    friend class turtle;
    friend class shell;
    friend class leg;
};
```

And make the `turtle`, `leg`, and `shell` class's constructor private, so only `TurtleFactory` instances would be allowed to actually create turtles.
Also the `leg` class would be friend-ed by dog, and the `shell` class friend-ed by `clam`.

This factory-based approach makes it clear that a turtle has four legs and a shell by looking at the code.

However, this would only be enforced if turtles were built "all-at-once". If, as I suspect, your software allows building "animals" piece-by-piece, interactively, this will not work.

In that case, components could carry dynamic type info, like this:

```
enum Type { TURTLE, CLAM, DOG, LEG, SHELL /* ... etc */ };

class node {
    virtual Type getType() = 0;
    virtual bool canAdd(Type t) = 0;

    void addChild(node * child) {
        if (canAdd(child->getType())
            // add node as child
    }
};

class leg {
    virtual Type getType() { return LEG; }
    ...
}

class turtle {
    ...
    virtual bool canAdd(Type t) { return t == LEG || t == SHELL; }
}
```

Each turtle could also count the number of added parts to disallow adding more parts than allowed:

```
    virtual bool canAdd(Type t) { 
        if (t == LEG && nLegs < 4) return true;
        else if (t == SHELL && nShell < 1) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately in my real-world problem, turtles, clams, and dogs can have an arbitrary number of shells and legs, and the user can interactively add/remove them at run time.  Yours is the approach I originally had in mind, but I thought there should be a "cleaner" way that didn't involve any kind of run-time type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your example is not  same as source task, but i should mention this:

You cannot inherit `turtle` from `leg`, so `leg` class can be inserted into `turtle` class only through composition. This means `turtle` users do not have direct access to `leg` class methods and you should implement them inside `turtle` and/or its parent. Or, as said in another answer, using interfaces.

I think best way to compse this classes is this:

1) Make all methods in `leg` class private to disable dirct inheritanse and/or composition.

2) Make a new class `LegMoving` which is **friend** class for `leg` and knows how to control the `leg`. `leg` will be a member for `LegMoving` class.

3) Inherit `turtle` from `LegMoving`

I think this way you do not violate base OOP patterns.

Answer (score 1):

**Ooops, I was just about to completely redesign my answer, when you accepted.**

But OK, take the following into account as additional information.

> *"I was thinking of making shell and leg class templates, where their parent type would be the template argument."*

In general this design pattern is known as the **[Curiously recurring template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)**, and serves as a good surrogate for dynamic polymorphism (runtime type checking).
If your use case just requires to construct these instances at compile time, you can get right off this way.

Think of a `legs` class template that provides a known number of legs for the concrete class

```
class leg : public node {
public:
    void moveForward(int speed) {
        // Any behavioral implementation
    }
};

template<class Impl, size_t LegsCount> 
class legs {
public:        
    // Provide a public interface to interact with legs
    void moveForward(size_t legIndex) {
        // Delegate behavioral implementation to Impl
        self->doMoveForward(legIndex);
    }
    size_t getLegsCount() const { return LegsCount; } 

    // eventually provide a default behavior that can be called from 
    // classes implementing the interface
    void doMoveForward(size_t legIndex) {
        if(legIndex >= LegsCount) {
            throw std::out_of_range();
        }
    }
protected:
    legs(const std::array<const std::array<leg,LegsCount>& legs) 
    : self(static_cast<Impl>(self)) 
    , legs_(legs) {
    }
private:
    Impl* self;
    std::array<leg,LegsCount> legs_;
};
```

further think of a shell class with certain traits

```
struct shell_base {
    const bool CanOpenShell;

    virtual void openShell() = 0;   

    shell_traits(bool canOpen = false) : CanOpenShell(canOpen) {}  
};

template<class Impl> 
class shell : public shell_base {
public:
    // Provide a public interface to interact with legs
    void openShell() {
        if(CanOpenShell) {
           // Check if the operation is applicable
           if(!CanOpenShell) {
               throw std::domain_error("Can't open shell.");
           }
           // Delegate behavioral implementation to Impl
           self->doOpenShell();
        }
    }

    void doOpenShell() {
    }

protected:
    shell(bool canOpen) : shell_traits(canOpen) {
    }
};
```

Your class declarations will look like this then

```
class turtle 
: public node
, public legs<turtle,4>
, public shell<turtle> {
public:
     turtle() 
     : legs<turtle,4>({leg(),leg(),leg(),leg()})
     , shell<turtle>(false) {
     }
     void doMoveForward(size_t legIndex) {
         // Let the base implementation check the range first
         legs<turtle,4>::doMoveForward(legIndex);

         // Call the specific behavior
         legs_[legIndex]->moveForward(10); // at slow speed
     }
};
```

---

```
class clam 
: public node
, public shell<clam> {
public:
     clam() : shell<clam>(true) {
     }
    void doOpenShell() {
         // Implementation
    }
};
```

---

```
class dog 
: public node
, public legs<dog,4> {
public:
     dog() : legs<dog,4>({leg(),leg(),leg(),leg()}) {
     }          
     void doMoveForward(size_t legIndex) {
         // Let the base implementation check the range first
         legs<dog,4>::doMoveForward(legIndex);

         // Call the specific behavior
         legs_[legIndex]->moveForward(100); // at fast speed
     }
};
```

Comment: Just as a follow-up, the CRTP article was useful for me and in fact I had used the concept already in some of my experimental code for this problem.  My current solution uses a mixture of concepts that have been proposed in this thread; namely multiple inheritance and using CRTP to avoid some run-time type checking.  Unfortunately my current solution still involves run-time polymorphism even though I know it could be eliminated.  However I think eliminating run-time type checking entirely would make for less-readable code and probably wouldn't add much in the way of actual performance anyway.